# pgfplots simple x filter error

Tags: pgfplots, errors, filter

In order to graph t as a function of n, I'm trying to filter rows in my file where k is different from 5. Here is the beamer :

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[aspectratio = 169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest, width = \textwidth, height = \axisdefaultheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Tree}
    \framesubtitle{ Time as a function of $n$}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                unbounded coords=discard,
            ]
            
                \addplot+ [
                    x filter/.expression={
                        \thisrow{k} == 5 ? x : nan
                    },
                ] table [
                    col sep = comma, 
                    x = n,
                    y = tmed,
                ] {./data/test-tree.csv};
                
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame} % This is line 137 in the full document
\end{document}
```

This results in the following error, which I have been able to isolate to the filter itself :

```
./presentation.tex:137: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   =
l.137 \end{frame}
                 ^^M
?
```

I'm a bit confused, because my filter is pretty much verbatim from the [pgfplots documentation](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-coordfiltering#pgfp./pgfplots/x:filter), but even copying and pasting their example doesn't work :

```latex
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot+[
        x filter/.expression={
            \thisrow{W} == 42 ? 0.2 : x
        },
    ] table {
        x y      W
        0 0      41
        0.5 0.5 42
        1 1      43
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

For reference, here is a sample of the `test-tree.csv` file : (~1900 lines omitted)

```
n, k, tq1, tmed, tq3
1, 1, 0, 1, 1
1, 2, 0, 1, 1
1, 3, 0, 1, 1
1, 4, 0, 1, 1
1, 5, 0, 1, 1
1, 6, 0, 1, 1
1, 7, 0, 1, 1
1, 8, 0, 0, 1
1, 9, 0, 1, 1
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Here you go (although in this case, it is a minimal *non-working* example)